# Androidアプリ内にzipファイルを格納したい

Tags: android, android-studio

Androidアプリのインストール時に、暗号化したzipファイルを同封したいのですが、
Assetsディレクトリに格納することで 実現できますでしょうか？
アプリ処理でzipを作成するのではなく、最初から同封したいです。